# Exchange 2007 rate limiting

Tags: smtp, exchange-2007

I have devices on the network that send out email alerts for misc things.  The other night there was a condition that caused one of the devices to send a few thousand emails to a couple of internal users.  Thankfully it didn't take anything down but you can see how it has the potential to.  All the devices connect to a receive connector on one of the transport servers.  The devices don't often have a built-in limiter so I figure the best place to manage this is on the Exchange side.

**Actual Question**

How can I set a limit/throttle on the number of emails that can go through the connector?

Comment: **Thankfully it didn't take anything down but you can see how it has the potential to**. How so? Exchange is a high performance enterprise and ISP grade email server. How are a few thousand emails going to bring it down?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joe...and you simply don't have any raw performance data to go by.  A few thousand 8kb emails going to internal mailboxes on the same Exchange server or a few thousand 20MB emails going to various external recipients?

The part you are probably looking for is (copy/paste from http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/managing-receive-connectors-part2.html for citation):

> We can also restrict the number of recipients, Rate Limit and Max
> message size at connector level, to configure these settings we can
> use the following parameters:
>
> MaxRecipientsPerMessage: The maximum number of recipients in a single message, the default value is 200.
>
> MaxMessageSize:  The maximum size of a message; the default value is 10MB.
>
> MaxRateLimit: This specifies the maximum number of messages that can be sent by the same client per minute.
>
> Let’s change our Internet Receive connector to accept 100 users
> maximum, the message size should be more than 2MB and the rate limit
> is 200, as follows:
>
> `Set-ReceiveConnector<Connector Name> –MaxRecipientsPerMessage:100 –MaxMessageSize:5MB –MaxRateLimit:200`

Comment: Doesn't work. Command not found in the Shell.